# mysql query-How to find if the parts of a pair havent a common characteritic

Tags: mysql

I try to display each pair of actors, the two actors have not played on anyone common movie genre while at the same time the genre that one has played together with the genre which has been played by the other being at least 7.

I did this:

```
SELECT a1.actor_id as i8opoios1,a2.actor_id as i8opoios2 FROM actor as a1
INNER JOIN actor as a2 on a1.actor_id != a2.actor_id
INNER JOIN role as r1 on a1.actor_id = r1.actor_id
INNER JOIN movie as m1 on m1.movie_id = r1.movie_id
INNER JOIN movie_has_genre as mg1 on mg1.movie_id = m1.movie_id
INNER JOIN genre as g1 on mg1.genre_id = g1.genre_id
INNER JOIN role as r2 on a2.actor_id = r2.actor_id
INNER JOIN movie as m2 on m2.movie_id = r2.movie_id
INNER JOIN movie_has_genre as mg2 on mg2.movie_id = m2.movie_id
INNER JOIN genre as g2 on mg2.genre_id = g2.genre_id
WHERE g1.genre_id!=g2.genre_id
 AND a1.actor_id='3226' 
GROUP BY a1.actor_id,a2.actor_id
HAVING IF((count(distinct(g1.genre_name))+count(distinct(g2.genre_name)))>=7,1,0) = 1;
```

But the results I get aren't the ones I want cause I get pairs of actors that played on the same genre of movie.I tried doing it with a subquery but I didnt got any results.

```
Tables and their columns:

actor(actor_id,name)
role(actor_id,movie_id)
movie(movie_id,title)
movie_has_genre(movie_id,genre_id)
genre(genre_id,gender_name)
```

Comment: Note that `HAVING IF(<condition>, 1, 0) = 1` is the same as `HAVING <condition>`.

Comment: What is a "common movie genre"?

Comment: every actor has played in several movies that have a genre.I want two actors who have in movies of different genre what do I mean by that:

Comment: actor1 played on Comedies and Thrillers so I want actor2 to play on anything else apart from Comedies and Thrillers

Comment: Try to remove the WHERE condition `g1.genre_id!=g2.genre_id` and add a HAVING condition `SUM(g1.genre_id=g2.genre_id) = 0` instead. Note I didn't check if your JOINs are correct.

Comment: Thank you very much that was exactly what i needed!My joins were right btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I wrote in my comment, you need to remove the WHERE condition `g1.genre_id!=g2.genre_id` and add a HAVING condition `SUM(g1.genre_id=g2.genre_id) = 0` instead.

Other notes:

- `HAVING IF(<condition>, 1, 0) = 1` is the same as `HAVING <condition>`
- DISTINCT is not a function. While `distinct(g1.genre_name)` also works - The correct syntax is `distinct g1.genre_name`.
- You don't need to join the `genre` table. You can use `movie_has_genre.genre_id` instead of and `genre.genre_id` and `genre.genre_name`

The final query:

```
SELECT a1.actor_id as i8opoios1,a2.actor_id as i8opoios2 FROM actor as a1
INNER JOIN actor as a2 on a1.actor_id != a2.actor_id
INNER JOIN role as r1 on a1.actor_id = r1.actor_id
INNER JOIN movie as m1 on m1.movie_id = r1.movie_id
INNER JOIN movie_has_genre as mg1 on mg1.movie_id = m1.movie_id
INNER JOIN role as r2 on a2.actor_id = r2.actor_id
INNER JOIN movie as m2 on m2.movie_id = r2.movie_id
INNER JOIN movie_has_genre as mg2 on mg2.movie_id = m2.movie_id
WHERE a1.actor_id='3226' 
GROUP BY a1.actor_id,a2.actor_id
HAVING count(DISTINCT mg1.genre_id) + count(DISTINCT mg2.genre_id))>=7
   AND SUM(mg1.genre_id = mg2.genre_id) = 0;
```

Answer (score 0):

The right answer:

```
SELECT a1.actor_id as i8opoios1,a2.actor_id as i8opoios2 FROM actor as a1
INNER JOIN actor as a2 on a1.actor_id != a2.actor_id
INNER JOIN role as r1 on a1.actor_id = r1.actor_id
INNER JOIN movie as m1 on m1.movie_id = r1.movie_id
INNER JOIN movie_has_genre as mg1 on mg1.movie_id = m1.movie_id
INNER JOIN genre as g1 on mg1.genre_id = g1.genre_id
INNER JOIN role as r2 on a2.actor_id = r2.actor_id
INNER JOIN movie as m2 on m2.movie_id = r2.movie_id
INNER JOIN movie_has_genre as mg2 on mg2.movie_id = m2.movie_id
INNER JOIN genre as g2 on mg2.genre_id = g2.genre_id
WHERE a1.actor_id='3226' 
GROUP BY a1.actor_id,a2.actor_id
HAVING IF((count(distinct(g1.genre_name))+count(distinct(g2.genre_name)))>=7,1,0) = 1
AND SUM(g1.genre_id=g2.genre_id) = 0;
```